# Passing ArrayXd to const VectorXd& and const Ref<const VectorXd>&

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

Is my understanding correct about the efficiency of the two functions?

```
VectorXd v;

void Foo(const ArrayXd&);
void Boo(const Ref<const ArrayXd>&);

// a temporary is created?
Foo(v);
// no temporary is created?
Boo(v);
```

Also, I also see in [eigen's doc](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html) some signature like `Boo` but without the `&`. Does it have any practical difference from `Boo` above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your understanding is correct.

Regarding the signature of `Boo` see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21138316/1641621).