# Function that takes VectorXf and can modify its values

Tags: c++, eigen

I am trying to understand how to manipulate Eigen Vector/Matrix. I would like to implement a least-square gauss-newton algorithm (hence why I am learning to use the Eigen library). I have a 1x6 vectors of parameters that I need to update each iteration. Right now, I just want to figure out how a function can take a vector as argument and change its values...

```
Eigen::VectorXf betas = Eigen::VectorXf::Zero(6);

void SomeFunc(const Eigen::VectorXf& v){  // as per the Eigen guide, one must pass as const
    v(0) = 5;  // error: expression must be a modifiable lvalue
    return;
}

int main()
{
    betas(5) = 5.f;  // works
    SomeFunc(&betas);
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    std::cout << betas(0) << "\t" << betas(5) << std::endl;
}
```

My question is: How would you make a function take a vector and modify its values?

Edit: [Eigen guide](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html)

Comment: Replace `const Eigen::VectorXf& v` with `Eigen::VectorXf& v`

Comment: `v` is marked `const` in you function so you cannot change it. Your compiler should tell you something similar. To modify it, remove the `const`

Comment: I'd like to read that Eigen guide and it's reason that you **must** pass as a const reference. Maybe you have misinterpreted the guide? Can you provide a link.

Comment: @JasonLiam, https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html says: `Functions taking writable (non-const) parameters must take const references and cast away constness within the function body.`
How does one cast away constness? None of the examples show how to do so (from what I could understand at least).

Comment: @Samito That seems strange. I mean why not just pass a non const lvalue reference instead of passing a const reference and then casting away constness.

Comment: @Samito The guide shows you how `const_cast<Eigen::VectorXf&>(v)(0) = 5;` Just wrap `v` in the appropriate `const_cast`

Comment: @JasonLiam The guide claims this may fail to compile. I've not tested it and have no idea why, but they seem to know what they are talking about.

Comment: @john, thanks, I hadn't understood this. It works, I'll be digging why :)! Thank you.

Comment: @Samito If you have a lot of these casts to make then you should just be able to do it once, and save the result e.g. `Eigen::VectorXf& vv = const_cast<Eigen::VectorXf&>(v); vv(0) = 5; vv(1) = 6; vv(2) = 7;` etc.

Comment: The reason to take these Eigen type by const ref is the corner case where you operate on sliced matrix (like in the example `cov(x,y, C.block(0,0,3,3));`). Compiler does not allow to bind the temporary to non-const ref, even though we know that this matrix slice is in fact a shortcut to `MatrixXf C`

Comment: You can pass `v` as a non-const `VectorXf&` in your case (as long as you only pass `VectorXf` objects -- `matrix.col(0)`, etc would not work). For a more generic solution, I recommend `Ref<VectorXf> v` -- see here for details: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html#title1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the purpose of that section of the documentation is to make you aware of the potential pitfalls that come from the various temporary objects that `Eigen` creates as it goes through various operations. You can write functions that take writable references such as `foo(Eigen::VectorXf &vector)` and it will work.  One problem that can occur with this is if you pass a slice of a matrix into the function thinking it is vector linked back the parent matrix.  What you actually pass into the function is a temporary vector that will be destroyed.  If you are 100% certain of what you are passing you can use references directly.  Otherwise there are safer things to do as suggested by the documentation.  Here are 3 versions of the same function.

You can see [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21132538/correct-usage-of-the-eigenref-class) for a discussion of the correct usage of the `Eigen::Ref` class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

void SomeFunc(Eigen::Ref<Eigen::VectorXf> v);
void SomeFunc2(Eigen::VectorXf &v);
void SomeFunc3(const Eigen::VectorXf &v);

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    Eigen::VectorXf betas = Eigen::VectorXf::Zero(6);
    
    std::cout << "Original\n";
    std::cout << betas << '\n';
    
    SomeFunc(betas);

    std::cout << "SomeFunc\n";
    std::cout << betas << '\n';

    betas.setZero();
    SomeFunc2(betas);

    std::cout << "SomeFunc2\n";
    std::cout << betas << '\n';

    betas.setZero();
    SomeFunc3(betas);

    std::cout << "SomeFunc3\n";
    std::cout << betas << '\n';

    return 0;
}

void SomeFunc(Eigen::Ref<Eigen::VectorXf> v) {
    v(0) = 5;
}

void SomeFunc2(Eigen::VectorXf &v) {
    v(2) = 5;
}
void SomeFunc3(const Eigen::VectorXf &v) {
    const_cast<Eigen::VectorXf&>(v)(4) = 5;
}
```

To quote from the linked question above:

> So in summary, we could recommend Ref for a writable reference, and const Ref& for a const reference.

Answer (score 3):

As the documentation says:

> Functions taking writable (non-const) parameters must take const references and cast away constness within the function body.

---

> How would you make a function take a vector and modify its values?

You can use `const_cast` as shown below:

```
Eigen::VectorXf betas = Eigen::VectorXf::Zero(6);

void SomeFunc(const Eigen::VectorXf& v){  // as per the Eigen guide, one must pass as const
    const_cast<Eigen::VectorXf&>(v)(0) = 5;//cons_cast used here
    return;
}

int main()
{
    betas(5) = 5.f;  // works
    SomeFunc(betas);
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    std::cout << betas(0) << "\t" << betas(5) << std::endl;
}
```