# Error passing Eigen matrix to a function in C++: "no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list"

Tags: c++, c++11, eigen

I have a script that is working fine, but when I try to write a function with the same script I get the error "no instance of overloaded function "aapx" matches the argument list".

I know that an Eigen::Matrix should always be passed by reference to a function so I did and I thought maybe the issue is I am initializing a  `Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<double>` and passing a `Eigen::MatrixXcd`  but that doesn't seem to fix the error either.

The function

```
void aapx(const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::MatrixXcd>& uh, Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::MatrixXcd>& vh, Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::MatrixXcd>& ph){ 
//some calculations

}
```

The main code looks like:

```
static const int nx = 10;
static const int ny = 10; 

Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<double>, (ny+1), (nx)> uh;
uh.setZero();

Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<double>, (ny+1), (nx)> vh;
vh.setZero();

Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<double>, (ny+1), nx> ph;  
ph.setZero();

aapx(uh,vh,ph); //ERROR
```

I can post the full code if necessary. The full error:

```
no instance of overloaded function "aapx" matches the argument list
argument types are: (Eigen::Matrix<std::_Complex<double>, 11, 10, 0, 11, 10>, Eigen::Matrix<std::_Complex<double>, 11, 10, 0, 11, 10>, Eigen::Matrix<std::_Complex<double>, 11, 10, 0, 11, 10>)
```

Comment: The whole code will not be as useful as a *MRE* or minimal reproducible example. Having a working example on compiler explorer (godbolt.org) really helps engagement. You can have library dependencies there too - Eigen is supported.

Comment: I dont think that is the full error. I believe there might be more. When this type of error occurs, the compiler prints a list of candidates as well and the reason for rejection.

Comment: See here one MRE example: https://godbolt.org/z/dsG5oEPM4

Comment: @MadFred Thanks! I added my full code here, in this link for you to run. Except I am not sure how to include an ``fftw3`` library in an online compiler like this.
https://godbolt.org/z/hTzjoETe9

Comment: @Jamie If you want to have additional libraries for godbolt, you can make a feature request: https://github.com/compiler-explorer/compiler-explorer/issues (Or download it and run it locally)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your third argument, `ph` needs to be

```cpp
Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::MatrixXcd> ph
```

(without the reference) and not

```cpp
Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::MatrixXcd>& ph
```

because `ph` is already a reference. You do not want to change the reference, you want to change the matrix.

Check out this answer: [Correct usage of the Eigen::Ref<> class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21132538/correct-usage-of-the-eigenref-class)

Comment: It should be either `const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::MatrixXcd>& ph` (for read-only arguments) or `Eigen::Ref<Eigen::MatrixXcd> ph` for read-write arguments.

Comment: @chtz It's a special case within Eigen since they implement their own types of references. It's explained in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21132538/correct-usage-of-the-eigenref-class

Comment: I know, and to quote from ggael's answer: "So in summary, we could recommend Ref<T> for a writable reference, and const Ref<const T>& for a const reference." I.e., replace your `Ref<const T>` by `Ref<T>`.

Comment: Thanks everyone this seemed to fix the issue. I do have another issue inside the function that has to do with ``ph``, that I will look into. One thing though, what do you mean by read-only arguments?

Comment: @Jamie when you pass by reference you have the possibility to modify the contents of that argument. By making it const you prevent it.